# Collect or group by date, ignoring the time

Tags: date, arangodb, aql

I have a list of `task` with a `date` property (ISO8601) and I want to group them by the date while ignoring the time set on the ISO8601.

```
FOR task IN tasks
    COLLECT date = task.date INTO tasksInDate = task
    SORT date DESC
    RETURN {
        "date": date,
        "tasks": tasksInDate
    }
```

This will group exactly on the datetime. Is there a way for ignoring the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is possible to collect only by the first 10 digits of a datetime value. If the format is "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MMMZ" (or similar), then the first 10 digits should contain the date part only:

```
FOR task IN tasks
  COLLECT date = SUBSTRING(task.date, 0, 10) INTO tasksInDate = task
  SORT date DESC
  RETURN {
    "date": date,
    "tasks": tasksInDate
  }
```